# How do i install requirements-dml.txt (im trying to install Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI)

Tags: python, pip, runtime-error, syntax-error, metadata

```
pip install -r requirements-dml.txt isnt working

Collecting joblib>=1.1.0 (from -r requirements-dml.txt (line 1))

Using cached joblib-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)

Collecting numba==0.56.4 (from -r requirements-dml.txt (line 2))

Using cached numba-0.56.4.tar.gz (2.4 MB)

Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> [10 lines of output]

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qmf8_7b4\numba_b9cd0db1bcfa4b2c9e38b486a39dfb38\versioneer.py:335: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'

LONG_VERSION_PY['git'] = '''

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 2, in <module>

File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>

File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qmf8_7b4\numba_b9cd0db1bcfa4b2c9e38b486a39dfb38\setup.py", line 51, in <module>

_guard_py_ver()

File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qmf8_7b4\numba_b9cd0db1bcfa4b2c9e38b486a39dfb38\setup.py", line 48, in _guard_py_ver

raise RuntimeError(msg.format(cur_py, min_py, max_py))

RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.7,<3.11 are supported.

[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.

╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

hint: See above for details.
```

For the requirement-dml.txt to actually works and I can move on with my life.

Comment: What part of the error message "Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.7,<3.11 are supported." you do not understand?

Comment: oh wait, I did not see that...thx